# check if bone belongs to a group

Tags: python

how to check if a bone belongs to a group? like this:

```
body_armature = bpy.data.objects['myrig']
for pbone in body_armature.pose.bones:
    if pbone.bone in body_armature.pose.bone_groups['mygroup']. ????():
```

items and values mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BoneGroup.html) fail with  "this type doesn't support IDProperties" :(

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups aren't handled as well as they might be because they don't maintain back pointers.  Here's one approach that relies on a [`PoseBone`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html) pointing to the [`BoneGroup`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BoneGroup.html#bpy.types.BoneGroup)

```py
import bpy
 
body_armature = bpy.data.objects['myrig']
pose = body_armature.pose
bone = pose.bones['top']
group = body_armature.pose.bone_groups['mygroup']
if bone.bone_group == group:
    print("gotcha")
else:
    print("nope")
```

so your loop would be replaced by

```py
body_armature = bpy.data.objects['myrig']
for pbone in body_armature.pose.bones:
    if pbone.bone.bone_group == body_armature.pose.bone_groups['mygroup']:
        print(f"bone {pbone.bone.name} is in mygroup})
```

Comment: works perfectly! thank you!